# New host without transferring domain or effecting emails.

Tags: domain, hosting, transfer

My client has a website hosted at "website.com"

They purchased hosting from a new provider. I have log in details but can't get to the hosting because the client's domain is pointing to their existing hosting.

I need to 
a) Remove the existing site at "website.com"
b) Put the new site in it's place, but on the new hosting, so it shows up at "website.com"
c) Do this without affecting their email accounts.

I'm quite green with this and don't know where to start.
The initial advise was to update the domain name servers to point to the new hosting, but this will kill the email accounts @website.com

Can anyone advise and explain in simple terms? 
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can short circuit DNS by entering the IP and domain into your hosts file locally.

```
1.2.3.4 example.com example.com
```

Two, you can address the new host by IP address, then FTP/SSH in to set it up.

Three, email is controlled by DNS MX records. Just ensure they're unchanged when you change the domain A records and you'll be fine. If you have no MX records then create them. Where will email be hosted, on the old server, the new server, or somewhere else like Google Apps?

Fourth, this stuff is really really basic, I don't mean to be rude or impolite but if you don't know this stuff you should probably get someone who's more experienced to do it. If you take out their web hosting and email for days they won't thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Tim, I appreciate this is basic but it's the first time I've had this situation. We all have to start somewhere. Thanks again, all sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean they're moving their website from one website host to another website host then change the DNS record(s) related to the website **ONLY**. You don't need to make any other changes in DNS. Do not make changes to their MX records, NS records or any other records not related to the website.